# Disassembler not appearing Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, disassembly

As someone coming from Eclipse, I am new to Visual Studio. I am attempting to access the disassembly window, and the msdn documentation is not providing a working solution.

I go to

> Debug > Windows

but fail to see disassembly listed as an option. Is this a glitch in the latest update of VS2015? Some assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the dissassembly window, you must be in debug mode.

To go into debug mode,
First set a breakpoint by

> right clicking on a line -> breakpoint -> insert breakpoint.

Then, go to

> debug -> start debugging

Finally, while in debug mode, click on

> debug->windows->dissassembly to open the dissassembly window